# Understanding port number

Tags: networking

Can somebody give me an example about how port number is working in the URL?
I wrote a toy flask app and the default port number is 5000, without any specification in my code. How does that happen?
Thank you

Comment: Can you give some further detail, what are you using as a web server and how are you configuring it?

Comment: For instance, when we write a toy flask app which just return 'hello world', the way we see our results is
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
I know like for FTP, we're using port 20. So what is port number representing? Is it like different 'sub-ip address'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the port number as a door through which an application on your computer is accessed by.

When you run a program on your computer that communicates with the outside world it needs to be assigned a port through which it can send and receive data, each port can only have one program associated with it as that's how your computer knows where to send the data.

So furthering the door analogy you can think of 127.0.0.1:5000 as
Go to the address 127.0.0.1
And use door 5000

As far as why your flask app is using port 5000, that's just the default port of the flask development server.
If you want to have your development server run on a different port you can run

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=****
```

With **** being the port you want to run on (According to [this](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2661) issue)
Then run

```
export FLASK_APP=hello.py
flask run
```

According to the [quickstart guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/)

If you want to read more about ports [here](https://whatismyipaddress.com/port) and [here](https://blog.udemy.com/computer-ports/) is some further reading.

Comment: "_You can think of the port number as a door through which your computer is accessed by._" It's more like the door to the application in the computer from a transport protocol that uses port numbers (not all do). Even at that, the same port number in different protocols is a different port in each protocol; TCP port 5000 is not UDP port 5000, and IP knows nothing of port numbers.

Comment: @RonMaupin I was drastically simplifying, like you pointed out there's much more to it. That being said the point that its more of a door to an application is important.